# How to get the user who has modified the file C #

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I developed an application that monitors events in the filesystem using the `FileSystemWatcher` class and would like to leave it installed on the file server as it happens that I need to register the user who accessed the file over the network.

Note: locally I know I can use:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent ().
```

or

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                  new ManagementObjectSearcher ("SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get ();
```

or

```
string owner = System.IO.File.GetAccessControl(pathOriginal).GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();
```

and the network?